# Restore ZEBRA to initial configuration programmatically

Tags: zpl-ii

I've used ZEBRA Z6M for a long time to print labels.
We are now trying new ERP software, which prints its own labels.

**My problem** : when I want to print again from my old program, the printer seems to receive data (LED lights up on the panel) but nothing is printed.

I think the new software sent some code to the printer, to change the configuration.

**My question** : which code should I send to the printer to put it back to its initial configuration?

Thanks a lot for help

Answer (score 1):

You can try commands:

```
~JR – Power On Reset
```

to resets all of the printer’s internal software, performs a
power-on self-test (POST), clears the buffer and DRAM, and resets communication
parameters and default values.

```
~JUN - reload factory network settings

~JUF - reload factory settings
```

Or go to control panel, printers, zebra driver preferences, tools and reset to the factory default values and/or reset a printer.